# PostgreSQL increment values of rows in a table

Tags: php, postgresql, simultaneous

I'm currently PHP building a script that has to update statistics when it finishes it's purpose. The script is accessed by web browser and depending on the traffic it may be executed simultaneously. I have to guarantee the statistics are right.

To give you the picture let's say we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE statistics(
  user_id      integer NOT NULL,
  date         integer NOT NULL, -- for unix time
  stat1        integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  stat2        integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  stat3        integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  -- and so on...
);

-- Let's insert some testing data for a couple of users and days...
-- Day one
INSERT INTO statistics(1, 1303520820, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO statistics(2, 1303520820, 1, 1, 1);
-- Day two
INSERT INTO statistics(1, 1303603200, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO statistics(2, 1303603200, 1, 1, 1);
-- Day three
INSERT INTO statistics(1, 1303689600, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO statistics(2, 1303689600, 1, 1, 1);
```

Every day a new row is inserted in the table so we could have a daily, weekly, monthly, yearly statistics. I have to be sure only one row is inserted per **user_id** per day. Also whenever an UPDATE query is executed it would increment the columns **stat1**,**stat2**,**stat3** appropriately.

This script is expected to have quite some traffic and I want to figure out how to make things work when the script is executed and has a couple of instances working simultaneously. What method/technique do you find best for such tasks ?

Comment: One row per day or one row per user_id per day? Whichever one you want to guarantee, `primary key` and `unique` are your friends.

Comment: One row per user_id per day. I'll correct that - sorry for the mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a unique constraint

```
CREATE TABLE statistics(
  user_id      integer NOT NULL,
  date         integer NOT NULL, -- for unix time
  stat1        integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  stat2        integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  stat3        integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  -- and so on...
  UNIQUE(user_id,date)
);
```

You should definitely do this regardless of what other measures you take.

Comment: Yes I though about that. Most probably I'll add UNIQUE only to the date column. I can't add it to the user_id column as the table can have endless rows with the same user_id :)

Comment: On second though I can't add Unique constraint to the structure. See the example in the question. The user_id can be the same and the date can be the same. Every user gets a new record in the database for every day.

Comment: `UNIQUE(user_id,date)` means that every combination of user_id and date must be unique, it is NOT the same as `UNIQUE(date),UNIQUE(user_id)`, i.e. there can only be 1 row per user per date, rather than 1 row per user and 1 row per date.

Comment: The OP will also need a trigger, I think. The trigger would determine whether to insert or update a row, and to implement the arithmetic.

Comment: @catcall, i would use a procedure not a trigger for that

Comment: I was talking about a trigger calling a procedure. A bare procedure can be bypassed by application code or a sleep-deprived DBA.

Comment: Not sure whether you're joking, but a unique constraint doesn't guarantee that all inserts and updates will go through the procedure. With suitable REVOKEs on the base tables, a procedure can protect the table from application code that exercises bad judgement. But you need more than that to protect the table from a DBA that's using bad judgement. Of course, it could be that I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Catcall, i mean that a unique constraints prevent you insterting duplicates which is the point, using triggers to enforce business logic in case a dba does something wrong is a bit crazy in my opinion!!

Comment: The OP's problem isn't just an issue of missing a primary key or unique constraint. The OP also needs to either insert (if the key doesn't exist) or update (if the key does exist).

Answer (score 1):

You need a unique constraint on the pair user_id and date, as others have said.

In order to insert without doing arithmetic when the compound key (user_id, date) doesn't exist, and to update with arithmetic when the compound key *does* exist, you need to write some code. Informally, this is called an "upsert". There's more than one way.

[PosgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) have an example of a function that implements this kind of requirement using exception handling. The problem with a function is that you can't force application code or database girls to use it every time without exception.

You can (I think) use the [suppress_redundant_updates_trigger()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464750/postgres-upsert-insert-or-update-only-if-value-is-different). The advantage of triggers is that they can't be bypassed accidentally by application code or by database girls. I have not used this technique myself, so I can't comment further on it. This trigger is documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-trigger.html).

You can also [handle the upsert logic with a user-defined trigger](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2009/06/approaches-to-upsert.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add CHECK for date value to ensure that it a multiple of 1 day:

```
ALTER TABLE "statistics" ADD CONSTRAINT "1day_quantum" CHECK ("date" = ("date" / 86400)::INTEGER * 86400);
```

Then exception will be thrown if one try insert wrong value of date.

If date field type will be TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMPTZ then CHECK is more complicated:

```
ALTER TABLE "statistics" ADD CONSTRAINT "1day_quantum" CHECK ("date" = TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + ((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "date") / 86400)::INTEGER * 86400) * INTERVAL '1 second');
```

By changing 86400 (seconds count) you can adjust constraint to various quantum: 900 for 15 mins for example.